# How do I display/zoom-in-on/drag a 150MB bmp image on screen in a WPF application without it being choppy?

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, zooming, bmp

I have an application that has a large area in which an image is viewed.  The image fits on screen but has incredibly high resolution and is 150MB in size.  The program allows the user to zoom in on the image indefinitely and drag around the image on screen inside of the viewing area.  Everything works very smoothly for the first two levels of zoom, but once I zoom into the image several levels, dragging it around produces hugely choppy delays.  What are some ways that I could improve performance so that all operations continue to be smooth no matter how far that I zoom in?